# Creating a multi step form

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap and Im trying to create a multi step form with 3 steps but Im creating it without using bootstrap because I didnt find that multi step form component. But now to to the navigation part between steps, for example:

If we are in the step 1 and we click "go to step 2" i want to show the step 2 div. Then in this div we have the step 2 div content and also the buttons "go to step 3" and the button "go back to step 1". In the step 3 div we have the step 3 content and the buttons "go back to step 2" and "ok".

I was trying to do this jquery part using bootstrap tabs like this example:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

But Im not having success doing this for the multi step form. Do you know if its possible to do that navigation between step divs using the example above and how? Or needs to be a different method?

This is the code I have for the multi step form:

https://jsfiddle.net/jb9ow0jw/

**Note:** The user should only be able to interact with the "go to" and "go back" buttons not with the titles "Step 1", "Step 2" and "Step 3".

Comment: I'd simply use [Bootstrap Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) and programmatically disable certain steps/tabs. You can still have `previous` & `next` buttons and the tabs would act more like breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thanks, but for example in that case the user can click on the nav-link links, "Step 1", "Step2" and "Step 3". But he should only be able to interact with the buttons "go to step 2", "go back to step 1", etc.

Comment: Do you need to submit the form each time the user navigates between steps? If not, move the `form` tag outside all of the hidden divs/steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice example of what you're looking for:

[Form wizard (using tabs)](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();
    
    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);
    
        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

```css
.wizard {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.wizard > div.wizard-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.connecting-line {
    height: 2px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
    color:#555555;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
    
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
    color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.wizard .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ) {
    .wizard {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    span.round-tab {
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard li.active:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <section>
        <div class="wizard">
            <div class="wizard-inner">
                <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <form role="form">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                        <h3>Step 1</h3>
                        <p>This is step 1</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                        <h3>Step 2</h3>
                        <p>This is step 2</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                        <h3>Step 3</h3>
                        <p>This is step 3</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                        <h3>Complete</h3>
                        <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again. Im doing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jb9ow0jw/1/, it seems the same but the prev and next buttons dont work and the tabs are not disabled.

Comment: The JavaScript in that JSFiddle doesn't match the HTML. Your missing the class `wizard` and you don't have `nav-tabs` but `nav-pills`.

Comment: Thanks, but continues not working: https://jsfiddle.net/jb9ow0jw/5/ Do you know why?

Comment: There were lots of things not wired up correctly. Here's the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/jb9ow0jw/7/